# identifying duplicates withing a partition with different ID's

Tags: sql, duplicates, partition

i am new to SQL and Data analysis.
I have a scenario i am trying to identify using SQL partitions.
Basically i want to find duplicates [same first_name, last_name, suffix code and Zip code but only if the id's are different.

This query gives me only partial results which is not correct...i know i am missing a filter here and there.

```
SELECT i.party_id,
    I.FIRST_NM,
    I.LAST_NM,
    I.SFFX_CD,
    A.ZIP_CD,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY I.FIRST_NM,
    I.LAST_NM,
    I.SFFX_CD,
    A.ZIP_CD
    ORDER BY I.PARTY_ID) AS RN 
    FROM INDVDL I,
    PARTY_ADDR A
  WHERE I.PARTY_ID = A.PARTY_ID
```

i should only get the ones marked with ** and not the rest

PARTY_ID    FIRST_NM    LAST_NM SFFX_CD ZIP_CD  RN

```
886874  John    Doe Jr. 45402   1
886874  John    Doe Jr. 45406   1
934635  John    Doe Jr. 45406   2
886874  John    Doe Jr. 45415   1
886874  John    Doe Jr. 45415   2
886874  John    Doe Jr. 45415   3
886874  John    Doe Jr. 45415   4
886874  John    Doe Jr. 45415   5
886874  John    Doe Jr. 45415   6
**886874    John    Doe Jr. 45415   7
**934635    John    Doe Jr. 45415   8
934635  John    Doe Jr. 45415   9
934635  John    Doe Jr. 45415   10
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my suggestion.  Use window functions to get the minimum and maximum values of `PARTY_ID` for the groups you have in mind.  Then, filter to return only rows where these are different:

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT i.*, a.*,
             MIN(I.PARTY_ID) OVER (PARTITION BY I.FIRST_NM, I.LAST_NM, I.SFFX_CD, A.ZIP_CD) as min_pi,
             MAX(I.PARTY_ID) OVER (PARTITION BY I.FIRST_NM, I.LAST_NM, I.SFFX_CD, A.ZIP_CD) as max_pi
      FROM INDVDL I JOIN
           PARTY_ADDR A
           ON I.PARTY_ID = A.PARTY_ID
     ) ia
WHERE min_pi <> max_pi;
```

Note:  I fixed your `join` syntax to use explicit joins.  Simple rule:  never use commas in the `from` clause.

Also, I replaced the column lists with `*` for convenience.  Add in the columns you want.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. There could however be a scenario where we have more than 2 party_id's within the same partition.Would this query account for that?

Comment: @user3002581 . . . Of course.  If there is more than 1, then the minimum and maximum will be different.  If the value can be `NULL`, the logic is a bit more complicated, but you can still do something similar.